# What is the difference between Gnu Ed and the version of Ed that ships with Unix?

Tags: ed

I was wondering is there is any functional difference between Gnu Ed and the version of Ed which ships with BSD Unix systems? I am currently using Gnu Ed 1.17 on Debian 10 but discovered this page:

https://man.openbsd.org/ed

The man pages seem to differ:

https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html

Comment: I don't see much of a difference. https://man.openbsd.org/ed#LINE_ADDRESSING corresponds pretty closely to https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html#Line-addressing, https://man.openbsd.org/ed#COMMANDS to https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html#Commands. There are a few extra options in https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html#Invoking-ed, but that's about it.

Comment: The Gnu Ed manual doesn't seem to describe their (incompatible?) extensions to `ed`. However, the description of the `-G` command line switch says: "'
     Forces backwards compatibility. This affects the behavior of the
     `ed` commands `G`, `V`, `f`, `l`, `m`, `t` and `!!`. If the
     default behavior of these commands does not seem familiar, then
     try invoking `ed` with this switch."

Comment: See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html#Invoking-ed)

Comment: It seems that it basically boils down to the regular expressions: the original ed didn't know about the emacsish/perlish `\b`, `\w` escapes and a couple more.

Comment: It is a pity they have not provided more information as to what way these commands differ in Gnu Ed. I had not picked up your point about the regular expressions, although I did note that there is a startup option (-E) which allows the use of "extended" regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only have access to three *current* `ed` implementations:

1. OpenBSD 7.0 `ed` (expected to behave like `ed` on NetBSD, FreeBSD, and macOS, but I haven't tested this thoroughly).
2. GNU `ed` 1.14.2 and 1.16.
3. Plan 9 `ed` from `plan9port-20210323`.

I have tried to summarize the differences between these below, and I've also tried to add the expected behavior of some "POSIX compliant `ed`" (going by what [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html) says).

Only the differences that I have encountered in `ed`-related questions/answers here on U&L are mentioned, so I haven't tried to make a literature study of manuals, etc., to find everything. For example, most `ed` implementations provide extensions to the POSIX `ed` standard through extra commands and/or command-line options should be fairly self-evident from their manuals, and the POSIX `ed` specification also mentions some commands that were never standardized.

The supported variants of regular expressions depend partly on the system's regular expression library.  This means that the expression `` \` `` on a GNU system would match the start of a line (just like `^`) as shown in the GNU `ed` (info-)manual, whereas GNU `ed` on an OpenBSD system would not be able to use that. So I won't talk more about this.

These are some other differences:

- `#` as a comment character.

  - GNU:    `#` is a comment command.
  - BSD:    `#` is not a valid command.
  - Plan 9: Like BSD.
  - POSIX:  Like BSD.
- Behavior destroying unsaved work.

  - GNU:    `e`, `e !`, and `q` always fails on the first try if the buffer is unsaved.
  - BSD:    Like GNU, but using `-s` disables the warning.
  - Plan 9: Like GNU.
  - POSIX:  Like GNU.
- Exit status (this is a bit difficult to test thoroughly).

  - GNU:    Terminates with a non-zero exit status if the last command caused
    an error.
  - BSD:    Most errors cause non-zero termination only with `-s`.
  - Plan 9: Seems to never terminate with non-zero exit status.
  - POSIX:  Termination with a zero exit status means "Successful completion
    without any file or command errors."
- The `s///` command, but with only the first `/`.

  - GNU:    `s/RE` is an error.
  - BSD:    `s/RE` behaves like `s/RE/`, which is the same as `s/RE//p`, i.e.
    it replaces the substring matching the regular expression `RE`
    with nothing and prints the modified line.
  - Plan 9: Like BSD.
  - POSIX:  Like GNU.
- Using `^` as an address.

  - GNU:    `^` is an invalid address.
  - BSD:    `^` addresses the previous line, just like `-`.
  - Plan 9: Like BSD.
  - POSIX:  Permits `^` to be the same as `-`.
- Combining the printing commands `p`, `l`, and `n` (like `nl`), and repeating commands while doing so (as in `nlnl` or `pnnn`).

  - GNU:    Combining printing commands is allowed. Repeated commands are not permitted (although `pp`, `nn`, and `ll` are allowed since the standard allows adding `p`, `n`, or `l` to commands other than `e`, `E`, `f`, `q`, `Q`, `r`, `w`, or `!`).
  - BSD:    Combining printing commands is allowed. Repeated commands are permitted.
  - Plan 9: Combinations of two commands out of the three are permitted (not `nlp`). Repeated commands are not allowed.
  - POSIX:  The effect of combining printing commands is "unspecified".
- Upon receiving a HUP signal, the current editing buffer is saved in a file called `ed.hup` in the current directory.  If that fails, the buffer is written to `$HOME/ed.hup`.  What happens if these names already exist?

  - GNU: The file `ed.hup` in the current directory will be overwritten if it is a regular file and it's owned by the current user.  Otherwise, the file `$HOME/ed.hup` will be overwritten if it is a regular file owned by the current user.  Otherwise, the buffer is lost.
  - BSD: Like GNU, but the current buffer is also available in a temporary file whose name matches `/tmp/ed.*`.
  - Plan 9: Like GNU.
  - POSIX: Like GNU.